# Series of holomorphic functions

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $a $ be a positive real number. Show that the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty e^ {-n^az}$ converges pointwise if and only if $\mathrm {Re}(z) \gt 0$. Named the sum above $f_a $, use Morera's theorem to show that  $f_a $ is holomorphic in $\Pi =\{z:\mathrm {Re}(z)\gt 0\}$.

It is evident that if $\mathrm {Re}(z)\gt 0$, then $f _a (z) $ is finite: for $n $ big enough, $e^{-n^a}\lt e^{-2\log n}$ (since $a$ is positive), and $\sum e^{-2\log n} = \sum \frac 1 {n^2}$ converges. This doesn't change if one considers $e^{-n^ax}$ and  $ e^{-2x\log n }$, with $x $ a positive real; so the sum $\sum|e^ {-n^az}|$ converges for $z\in \Pi$. Since every term of the series is a holomorphic function of $z $, its integral over any triangle is zero; then the integral of $f_a$ over any triangle is an infinite sum of zeros, that is zero. Morera's theorem implies that $f_a $ is holomorphic in $\Pi $.

> Show that $f_1$ extends to a holomorphic function over $\mathbb C\setminus 2\pi i \mathbb Z$ and study its singularities.

I don't understand this part: how can one extend $f_1$ continuously to $\Pi \cup \mathbb R i \setminus 2\pi i \mathbb Z$, if $f_1$ is not finite in any point of $\mathbb R i ?$ Instead, if $f_1$ is actually finite in $\mathbb R i \setminus 2\pi i \mathbb Z$ (and so it isn't true that $f_a $ converges pointwise only if $z\in \Pi $), I could consider the sum as $\sum (e^{-z})^n=\frac 1 {1-e^{-z}}$ ($f_1(z)$ finite implies $|e^{-zn}|\to 0)$. This would mean that there is a simple pole with residue $1$ in every $z\in 2\pi i \mathbb Z$. However I don't see how could $\sum \sin (-nx)$ and  $\sum \cos (-nx)$ converge when $x\notin 2\pi i \mathbb Z$. Can anyone clarify my ideas? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you did in part 1 is correct. The series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty e^ {-n^az}$ converges if and only if $Re(z) > 0$.

Now let's go to the second part: As you are talking about an analytic continuation of $f_1$, you first have to specify a domain on which $f_1$ is holomorphic and from which you want to extend $f_1$. You did this in part 1 and found out that $f_1$ is holomorphic in $\Pi$. So you want to extend $f_1$ defined on $\Pi$. Now strictly speaking, your argument that $f_1$ cannot be continued to any point in $\mathbb R i$ because it is not finite there is wrong: $f_1$ is not **defined** there because now we only consider $f_1$ defined in $\Pi$. But of course, what you really wanted say is that $f_1$ is defined by $\sum_{n=0}^\infty e^ {-nz}$ in $\Pi$ and this series diverges for points in $\mathbb R i$ and so you expect that if you approach points in $\mathbb R i$, the value of $\sum_{n=0}^\infty e^ {-nz}$ will explode.

But if you write that down carefully you note that for this expectation to hold you need to exchange a limit and a series, which requires a justification. You need the equality
$$\lim_{z \to z_0, \ z \in \Pi} \sum_{n=0}^\infty e^ {-nz} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \lim_{z \to z_0, \ z \in \Pi} e^ {-nz} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty  e^ {-nz_0}$$
for $z_0 \in \mathbb{R} i$. The problem is that you cannot justify this step and it is indeed not true.

You can actually see that $f_1$ stays bounded near points in $\mathbb R i \setminus 2\pi i \mathbb Z$: As you correctly noted, $$f_1(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty e^ {-nz} = \frac 1 {1-e^{-z}}$$ for $z \in \Pi$ and it is clear that $\frac 1 {1-e^{-z}}$ stays bounded near points in $\mathbb R i \setminus 2\pi i \mathbb Z$.

Now in the end $\frac 1 {1-e^{-z}}$ defines a function which is holomorphic in $\mathbb R i \setminus 2\pi i \mathbb Z$ and it coincides with $f_1$ on $\Pi$. So it is the analytic continuation of $f_1$ you were searching for.

Comment: Thanks, you really understood my problem; now it is clear. I have just one more question: if I have a series of holomorphic functions (call the sum $f $ and suppose $f\lt \infty $ in an open $\Pi $) can I always use Morera's theorem like I did to prove that $f $ is holomorphic in $\Pi?$

Comment: Yes, but you have to ensure that the series converges uniformly on every triangle because you have to interchange the integral and the series for your argument to work. In your example this is true.